# Wordpress website mobile-menu main points doesn't link to sites

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I have a problem with the mobile menu on my wordpress website. It's this site: http://wp.abcdata-systeme.de

If you make your viewport smaller, so that the mobile navigation button shows up, you can click it and the mobile menu shows up.

My problem is following:
If I click on the main points in the navigation (like IT-Service, Reparatur or Unternehmen) nothing happens. But I would this main points like to open the sites, which are liked to them. In the Desktop Navigation it works perfect. If I click on "Reparatur", wp.abcdata-systeme.de/index.php/reparatur/ this links opens, if I click on IT-Service, wp.abcdata-systeme.de/index.php/it-service/ this link opens, and so on... On mobile nothing happens if I click them.

I modified the navigation like to display all of the links of the navigation at the same time. Prior the sublinks showed up in a dropdown, if i clicked on one of the mainpoints, but i didn't want this "feature".

So I know, that there is a javascript, that handles that but I don't know which one it is or what I have to change to make the main points link to their pages.

Maybe one of you guys can help me?

Greetings,
Linda

EDIT:
To make it work on Desktop I had to add this code to custom.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.ts-menu-destop').find('.menu-item-has-children').each(function() {
        $(document).on('click', 'li.menu-item-has-children > a', function(e){
            var $this = $(this);
            var href = $this.attr('href');
            if ($.trim(href) != '') {
                window.location = href;
            }       
        });     
    });

});
```

But it does not work on mobile... I want these links to work:
http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3983/36d8fdql_jpg.htm

Comment: Could you revert the code to when there wasn't any sub items showing, I want to take a look at something.

Comment: Hi Jordan! Thank you for your answer! You can take a look at the navigation before my modifies here: http://test.linda-polak.de/ :)

Comment: I don't see the problem? The navigation seems to work fine in multiple viewport sizes (mobile & tablet screens sizes) when testing in Safari & Chrome.

Comment: Yeah, on test.linda-polak.de it works somehow, but not like i want it. i want the main points with sub points to link to their sites, and thats not the case in both versions...
if a main point has subpoints, it just doesn't link to its site...

Comment: Can you paste some code in question?

Comment: From what I can see it's working as should, when you click on any of the the navigation items they all link to separate pages, and when you hover over the drop down lists they work as intended too. Have you tried clearing your cache?

Comment: Yes I cleared cache and tried it in chrome & safari, but in both it doesn't work...
I added some details in my question. Some code I had to add to make the links work on desktop and a screenshot of the "problem-links" in mobile

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. The class ".ts-menu-destop" from the desktop code didn't appear in the mobile code, so I changed it into the id "#menu-main-menu" which appears in both versions. That fixed the problem :)